# "INVALID USE OF AN AGGREGATE FUNCTION OR OLAP FUNCTION" ERROR IN DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have attached my code below for your review.  My error is coming with the 4th CASE statement where I am using math functions to calculate information.  Does anyone know what is causing the error and how to get around it?  I'm guessing that the issue is in my ORDER BY function at the end.

```
SELECT
H.DATE AS "DATE"
,TRIM(H.NUMBER) AS "NUMBER"
,CASE WHEN TT.RY_DATE IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CHAR(TT.RY_DATE) END AS "RY DATE"
,CASE WHEN T.PT_DATE = '0001-01-01' THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS "PT"
,T.ON AS "ON"
,CASE WHEN H.CLASS = '0.00' THEN H.CLASS ELSE H.RATED END AS "CLASS"
,SUBSTR(TRIM(S.NAME), 1, LENGTH(TRIM(S.NAME))-2) AS "CITY"
,H.STATE AS "STATE"
,H.ZIPCODE AS "ZIP"
,SUBSTR(TRIM(CN.NAME), 1, LENGTH(TRIM(CN.NAME))-2) AS "DCITY"
,H.STATE AS "DSTATE"
,H.ZIPCODE AS "DZIP"
,H.WGT AS "WEIGHT"
,CASE 
WHEN Q.AMOUNT IS NULL THEN (Y.CHGS - Z.AMOUNT)
WHEN Q.AMOUNT IS NOT NULL THEN (Y.CHGS - (SUM(Q.AMOUNT +  Z.AMOUNT))) ELSE ''
END AS "LL"
,Z.AMOUNT AS "FU"
,SUM(Q.AMOUNT) AS "AC"
,Y.CHGS AS "CHARGES"

FROM A.COST H

INNER JOIN A.MASTER S
ON H.CITY = S.CITY

INNER JOIN A.MASTER CN
ON H.CITY = CN.CITY

INNER JOIN A.SPEC Z
ON Z.NUMBER = H.NUMBER
AND Z.DATE = H.DATE
AND Z.TYPE = 'F'

INNER JOIN A.ALT Y
ON Y.NUMBER = H.NUMBER
AND Y.DATE = H.DATE

LEFT OUTER JOIN A.SPEC. Q
ON Q.NUMBER = H.NUMBER
AND Q.DATE = H.DATE
AND Q.TYPE = 'S'

LEFT OUTER JOIN A.T TT
ON H.NUMBER = TT.NUMBER

LEFT OUTER JOIN A.TIME T
ON T.NUMBER = H.NUMBER

WHERE H.CTRL = '000000'
AND (MONTH(CURRENT DATE)-1) = MONTH(H.DATE)
AND H.DATE > CURRENT DATE - 90 DAYS

GROUP BY
H.DATE 
,TRIM(H.NUMBER)
,CASE WHEN TT.D_DATE IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CHAR(TT.D_DATE) END
,CASE WHEN T.PT_DATE = '0001-01-01' THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END
,T.ON
,CASE WHEN H.CLASS = '0.00' THEN H.CLASS ELSE H.RATED END
,SUBSTR(TRIM(S.NAME), 1, LENGTH(TRIM(S.NAME))-2)
,H.STATE
,H.ZIPCODE 
,SUBSTR(TRIM(CN.NAME), 1, LENGTH(TRIM(CN.NAME))-2)
,H.STATE 
,H.ZIPCODE 
,H.WGT 
,CASE WHEN Q.AMOUNT IS NULL THEN (Y.CHGS - Z.AMOUNT)
WHEN Q.AMOUNT IS NOT NULL THEN (Y.CHGS - (SUM(Q.AMOUNT + Z.AMOUNT))) END
,Z.AMOUNT 
,Y.CHGS

ORDER BY DATE
```

Comment: But you are using `SUM()` in `GROUP BY` which will not work. Can you please try to explain your goal and reduce the query to relevant clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to reference both individual and aggregated `Q.AMOUNT` values in the SELECT.

If I understand your intention correctly, you probably meant to do this with your fourth CASE:

```
Y.CHGS - (COALESCE(SUM(Q.AMOUNT), 0) +  Z.AMOUNT) AS "LL"
```

If every `Q.AMOUNT` in a group is NULL, `SUM(Q.AMOUNT)` will be NULL as well and replaced with a zero, which will essentially make the expression equivalent to `Y.CHGS - Z.AMOUNT`.

You don't need to repeat this expression in GROUP BY as all references in it are either already GROUP BY criteria or being aggregated.

The `COALESCE` function accepts multiple arguments and returns the first one that is not NULL.

Answer (score 0):

In fourth case there is no use of using an extra `SUM` function. Try somthing like this:-

```
CASE 
WHEN Q.AMOUNT IS NULL THEN (Y.CHGS - Z.AMOUNT)
WHEN Q.AMOUNT IS NOT NULL THEN (Y.CHGS - Q.AMOUNT +  Z.AMOUNT) 
ELSE ''
END AS "LL"
```

Hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: The SUM function is necessary there and I will explain why.  Q.AMOUNT will be null if nothing exists.  However, there can be multiple line items for Q.AMOUNT if there is data present.  Therefore, I need the sum of that column + the Z.AMOUNT.  Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following from GROUP BY:

```
CASE WHEN Q.AMOUNT IS NULL THEN (Y.CHGS - Z.AMOUNT)
WHEN Q.AMOUNT IS NOT NULL THEN (Y.CHGS - (SUM(Q.AMOUNT + Z.AMOUNT))) END
```

Comment: When I do that I get the following error - An expression starting with "AMOUNT" specified in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the GROUP BY clause or it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause with a column function and no GROUP BY clause is specified.

Comment: you need to decide which fields you want to group by and which you want to calculate using aggregate functions. I don't really know which granularity you are trying to acheive.